# Finding ID with Multiple ASP UserControl using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP usercontrol name `ListItem`. Each `ListItem` has 2 ASP controls on it : a label `lblIndex` and a button `btnAction`

On my page, I load 10 `ListItem` into a panel and set `lblIndex` on each ListPanel an appropriate index.

```
ListItem 1 : lblIndex.value = '#1'
ListItem 2 : lblIndex.value = '#2'
...
ListItem 10 : lblIndex.value = '#10'
```

How do I write Javascript that, each time when I click the button on a `ListItem`, the appropriate `lblIndex`'s value will appear(through an `Alert()`). I.e. when I click the `btnAction` on the 2nd `ListItem`, the text '#2' will come out.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to facilitate your life, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) when writing javascript.

in that in mind, let's assume that your `ListItem` control outputs a `ul` list with an `id`... make sure that you had a class, let's imagine that you named `list-item` so at the end you will have:

```
<div id="ListItem_1" class="list-item">
   ...
</div>
```

Now, you say you some sort of a button inside that list...

```
<div id="ListItem_1" class="list-item>
   <input id="ListItem_1_Button_1" type="button" value="I'm a Button" />
</div>
```

Once again, explicit give that button a class name, for example: `inside-button`

I don't know how you have all texts, but I'll again assume that will be a `hiiden` field with the text to alert ...

some thing like:

```
<div id="ListItem_1" class="list-item>
   <input id="ListItem_1_Button_1" type="button" value="I'm a Button" />
   <input id="ListItem_1_Hidden_1" type="hidden" class="text" value="Text to run" />
</div>
```

and assuming you have 10 lists with several buttons you can simple write:

```
$(".inside-button").bind("click", function() {
    // a button was clicked, let's do something
});
```

that 1st line says: "Foreach DOM element that has a class name of `inside-button` attach the click event"

and inside you fire what you want to do

From your question, you only want to perform something on that list:

```
$(this)  // that will be the .inside-button element, so the Button
   .closest(".list-item")  // get me the closest DOM element with a class name of "list-item"
   .find(".text") // find the DOM elemnt with the class name "text"
   .val();  // let's see what value that element has
```

then you can `alert()` it.

All together:

```
$(".inside-button").bind("click", function() {
    // a button was clicked, let's do something
    var txt = $(this).closest(".list-item").find("text").val();
    alert( txt );
});
```